# Достать все объекты JSON по ключу в объекте

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Есть очень большой JSON вида:

```
{
 'id': 'someid',
 'type': 'group',
 'children': [
    {
     'id': 'someid',
     'type': 'group',
     'children': [
        {
         'id': 'someid',
         'type': 'person'
        }
     ]
    }
 ]
}
```

мне нужно вытащить все объекты используя Python, полный объект типа:

```
{
 'id': 'someid',
 'type': 'person'
}
```

если в объекте `type==person` (потом я эти объекты закину в список).
Как это сделать, если JSON реально большой и количество дочерних объектов children неизвестно и может меняться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто рекурсивно идёте по элементам и собираете нужные:

```py
def find_data(d, type_):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if d['type'] == type_:
            yield {'id': d['id'], 'type': d['type']}
        if 'children' in d:
            yield from find_data(d['children'], type_)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for x in d:
            yield from find_data(x, type_)
    else:
        raise ValueError(); 

data = {'id':'someid',
        'type':'group',
        'children':
            [{'id':'someid',
            'type':'group',
            'children':
                [{'id':'someid',
                'type':'person'}]}]}

result = list(find_data(data, 'person'))
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
[{'id': 'someid', 'type': 'person'}]
```

Если `person` конечный элемент и у него точно нет `children`, то чуть проще, вместо нового словаря с частью элементов `yield {'id': d['id'], 'type': d['type']}` можно возвращать весь текущий словарь `yield d`.

Comment: работает с локальным data из примера, но почему то в моем JSON с сервера выкидывает ошибку
if d['type'] == type_:
KeyError: 'type'

Comment: понял, структура json видимо сложнее и список ключей, полученный по list(data.keys()) не содержит ключ type, только несколько родительских ключей

Comment: Ну значит надо проверять наличие ключа и что-то делать или не делать, если его нет )

Comment: разобрался, спасибо!

Comment: Хорошее решение для небольших json файлов.

Но если json-ки реально большие, то рекурсия опасна, а загрузка всего файла в память не желательна. Тут велика вероятность отхватить название этого замечательного сайта)

Comment: @Tananndart Тут же через yield делается, ничего не копится нигде. Проблемы с рекурсией будут только если будет 1000 уровней вложенности в json или сколько там предел рекурсии. Тогда да, нужно будет смотреть другие варианты.

Comment: @CrazyElf имел в виду не сам алгоритм, а то что он работает с данными полностью загруженными в память. Т.е. для обработки надо будет большие файлы json в память загружать, обрабатывать и выгружать. Глубина рекурсии по умолчанию 1000, да, если не повезет, то все свалится и будет неприятно.

Answer (score 1):

Решение с помощью ijson без рекурсии и без загрузки всего json в память.

```
import ijson


def extract_filtered_json_objects(path_to_json, filter_key, filter_value):
    """
    Последовательно считывает json файл, затем возвращает список отфильтрованных json объектов.
    :param path_to_json: путь до json файла;
    :param filter_key: ключ фильтрации;
    :param filter_value: необходимое значение ключа фильтрации;
    :return: список из отфильтрованных json объектов.
    """
    results = []

    with open(path_to_json, 'r') as file:
        parser = ijson.parse(file)

        # Последовательно читаем json файл
        # prefix - это путь до текущей ноды;
        # event - это тип ноды, например start_map это начало списка, end_map это конец списка и т.д.
        # value - это значение текущего элемента (может принимать различные типы: None, строка, int и т.д.)
        for prefix, event, value in parser:
            # тут нас интересуют элементы списков в json и событие по нахождению какого-либо ключа в этом списке
            if prefix.endswith('.item') and event == 'map_key':
                # заготовка под объект json, который будем строить
                json_object = {}
                # пока в текущем списке есть элементы, будем их анализировать
                while event == 'map_key':
                    # ijson идет итеративно по ключам и значениям
                    # поэтому сначала сохраняем уже полученный ключ,
                    # а потом запускаем следующую итерацию для получения значения
                    key = value
                    _, _, value = next(parser)
                    json_object[key] = value
                    # для продолжения нашего while нам нужно снова перейти на следующий ключ списка
                    # поэтому в этой итерации мы специально сеттим event (там как раз будет map_key)
                    prefix, event, value = next(parser)

                # с построенным объектом json можем делать что угодно, тут мы сверяем его с фильтром и записываем
                if filter_key in json_object and json_object[filter_key] == filter_value:
                    results.append(json_object)

    return results


if __name__ == "__main__":
    json_file = "test3.json"
    
    persons = extract_filtered_json_objects(json_file, 'type', 'person')
    for person in persons:
        print(person)
```